# this.Loaded += (s, e) => this.loaded = true;?

Tags: events, c#-3.0, lambda

would someone please write this code:

this.Loaded += (s, e) => this.loaded = true;

into several code lines so I can retrace the meaning?

In my code sample there is no **s** or **e** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may make it slightly clearer, just by renaming:

```
this.Loaded += (sender, args) => this.loaded = true;
```

Or by giving them types:

```
this.Loaded += (object sender, EventArgs args) => this.loaded = true;
```

They're the parameters for the delegate. Here's the equivalent in C# 2:

```
this.Loaded += delegate (object sender, EventArgs args) { this.loaded = true; };
```

Does that help?

Here's the equivalent in C# 1 (fortunately there are no captured variables, which makes life a bit easier...)

```
this.Loaded += new EventHandler(SetLoadedToTrue);

...

private void SetLoadedToTrue(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.loaded = true;
}
```

(That's all assuming the `Loaded` event is of type EventHandler; if it's not, the signature would be different in the obvious way.)

Comment: Ahhh, mr. Skeet, why do I even bother answering C# questions when you are online ;-)

Comment: (Was in the middle of typing almost exactly this into an answer, but Jon Skeet > me)  To address the original question: just like how the names of the parameters to SetLoadedToTrue ("sender" and "args") are themselves variable declarations that don't appear elsewhere in the call site's code, the "s" and "e" in the lambda declaration are likewise declared for the scope of the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shorthand for an event handler. `s` is what you normally see as `object sender` and `e` is some type of `EventArgs`.
Basically it could be written like this:

```
public void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.loaded = true;
}
```

and the calling code would be something like:

```
this.Loaded += MyHandler;
```